# Where does Oracle NoSQL database fit in?

Tags: oracle, nosql, oracle-nosql

The various NoSQL database systems all make their own specific choices and tradeoffs, making them more or less suitable for different use-cases. Fortunately, there are many good comparisons (also here on Stackoverflow) that explain and contrast the ideas, strengths and weaknesses of all major players.

But I cannot find any independent information about what [Oracle NoSQL Database](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/nosqldb/overview/index.html) is, and where it fits in the NoSQL landscape. There is not even a Wikipedia page.

So, what is it, and how does it work?

Comment: The name of the product is also hard to google. Couldn't they have come up with a nice new brand name? Or is the NoSQL buzzword part of the sales pitch?

Comment: Sneaky PR is what it is.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I have found so far:

- It is a key-value store based on the (potentially modified) BerkeleyDB engine
- It manages a cluster of nodes across which the data is sharded and/or replicated
- It has the concept of major keys and minor keys. You can get atomic commits for the minor keys belonging to the same major key.
- The values associated to the keys are arbitrary binary data.
- Data is distributed across the storage using a hash function. As a result, you can apparently only iterate in on unordered fashion, and not do range searches (you can iterate minor keys of a given major key in order).
- You can configure durability by specifying how many replicas you want to have the data you are saving committed to
- It uses single-master replication, so you have a master with the guaranteed latest version of the data, and read-only slaves which may be slightly behind
- It is written in Java
- There is a commercial and an open-source community edition (the latter is currently pending release while a license review is going on)

Answer (score 2):

This is the most information I have seen about it, from a presentation at the High Performance Transaction Systems Conference:
http://hpts.ws/agenda.html
http://hpts.ws/sessions/cwl-hpts-for-website.pdf

From slide 9:

### What the Programmer Sees

- Simple data model – key-value pair (major/minor key paradigm)
- Simple operations – CRUD, RMW (CAS), iteration
- Conflict resolution not required
- ACID transactions for records within a major key, single API call
- Unordered scan of all data (non-transactional)
- Ordered iteration across sub keys within a key
- Consistency (read) and durability (write) spec’d per operation

Answer (score 0):

/. picking up on the issue right now, see [First Look: Oracle NoSQL Database](http://developers.slashdot.org/story/11/11/16/1948253/first-look-oracle-nosql-database)

after reading some of the comments I'm lead to believe Oracle just had to offer something in that category as well.

**Update after reading Zansons pdf:**

It's basicly built upon **Berkeley DB** and adds **dynamic partitioning** (“sharding”) ... "No single point of failure" sounds very impressive.

Does that mean it competes with Enterprise Edition partitioning and RAC? As a free (OSS) product?? Are they serious?

Comment: Yeah, that's how I heard about it, too. After RTFA I am still not clear on what it is.